# Autofill SQL table field with Datetime value based on input parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, stored-procedures, dateadd

I have a datetime field in my SQL table. I have created a procedure that takes count as a variable and generates records for the table. If the count is 5 it will generate 5 records.The logic i want is that when i provide 5 as an input parameter the datetime field in the table should be autofilled with values

```
12/20/2015 9:00
12/20/2015 11:00
12/20/2015 13:00
12/20/2015 15:00
12/20/2015 17:00
```

So every time a record is inserted into a table,the 2 hours of time should be added.

Comment: My bad. I use MS SQL-Server

Comment: Is there an upper and lower limit to the number of records you will be adding at any one time?  Also do you have some code you have tried?

Comment: dateadd(h, 2, previousDate)

Comment: Will it always start from current date 9 O Clock

Comment: Yes. This is an auto appointment kind of procedure. Where the start time will be next day 9:00 AM and based on the input parameter it will add 2 hours to each record. The minimum value will be 1 and maximum will be 6

Answer (score 0):

Recursive [CTEs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx) are one way to create records on the fly.  The key here is to create an anchor (this is the first SELECT inside the CTE, which is your starting point).  And an exit check (which is the WHERE clause).

Read up on MAXRECURSION if you want to create more than 100 records at a time.

Example

```
DECLARE @RecordsRequired    INT = 5;
DECLARE @BaseDateTime        SMALLDATETIME = GETDATE();


WITH [Sample] AS
    (
        /* This CTE uses recursion to create the required number of 
         * records.
         */
            SELECT
                1                AS RowNumber,
                @BaseDateTime    AS [DateTime]

        UNION ALL

            SELECT
                RowNumber + 1                    AS RowNumber,
                DATEADD(HOUR, 2, [DateTime])    AS [DateTime]
            FROM
                [Sample]
            WHERE
                RowNumber < @RecordsRequired 
    )
SELECT
    RowNumber,
    [DateTime]
FROM
    [Sample]
;
```

You could also look into [WHILE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms178642.aspx) blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
------------------ INPUT ------------------------
declare @start_date datetime = '01/01/2000 14:00'
declare @loops int = 5
-------------------------------------------------

declare @i int = 0
while (@i < @loops) begin 
    select dateadd(hour, @i * 2, @start_date)
    set @i = @i + 1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this without **LOOP**

```
Declare @count int = 5,
        @incrementer int =2 -- in case if you want to change the incrementer 

SELECT Dateadd(hh, num * @incrementer, dates) 
FROM   (SELECT Cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), Dateadd(dd, 1, Getdate()), 111) 
                    + ' 9:00 AM' AS DATETIME) AS Dates, 
               num 
        FROM   (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5)) TC (num)) A 
WHERE  num <= @count - 1
```

- [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/6371)

Answer (score 0):

```
Create Table dates
    (
    datetimefield datetime not null
    )
    go

Create Procedure FillDateTimeField
@insertxrows  int
AS
begin
Declare @LastDateTimeInserted as datetime
set @LastDateTimeInserted  = (select isnull(max(datetimefield),getdate()) from Dates)
;WITH norows AS (
  SELECT 1 as num, Dateadd(hour,2,@LastDateTimeInserted) as FirstRecord
  UNION ALL
  SELECT num + 1, dateadd(hour,2,firstrecord) FROM 
  norows
   WHERE num < @insertxrows
)
insert into dates
select firstrecord from norows
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find the sample code below, it contains the logic that you needed. Hope it helps!!

```
--Create a temp table for sample output 
CREATE TABLE #temp
( 
CreatedDate datetime
)

--Declaring variables
DECLARE @Count int
DECLARE @TimeCounter int
--intializing values
SET @Count=5
SET @TimeCounter=0


WHILE(@Count>0)
BEGIN
--SELECT getdate()+1
insert into #temp(#temp.CreatedDate) Select DATEADD(hour,@TimeCounter,getdate())
SET @TimeCounter=@TimeCounter+2
SET @Count=@Count-1
END
--Final values
SELECT * FROM #temp tmp
--Dropping table
DROP TABLE #temp
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those problems that's best solved with a numbers table / function. Much less code than recursion or loops, usually faster for anything non-trivial and more reusable too.

The core code you want is

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_PopulateAppointments
(
    @StartDateTime  datetime2(3),
    @Records        int,
    @Interval       int = 120       --Time between appointment slots in minutes. Default to 2h if not manually specified.
)

INSERT INTO Appointments
SELECT
    DATEADD(m, @Interval * Number, @StartDateTime)
FROM dbo.udfNumbers(0, @Recs)
```

I've assumed in this a numbers function that takes @StartAt and @NumberResults. I use one derived from Adam's final code in the comments on http://dataeducation.com/you-require-a-numbers-table/ - in my experience it's faster than a real table, and takes less space too.